# How to declare and assign Python Dataframe 'column name' as variable of two strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dynamic, while-loop

I have a DataFrame of Stocks with columns as `'SMA100915'`, `'SMA500915'` and so on...
`df['SMA100915']` is a column having Simple Moving Average value of the stock at 09:15 Hrs, likewise I'm collecting all the SMA's in different columns for analysis purpose using a `while` loop on `df`. This loop is scheduled to run every 15 mins from 09:15 Hrs

Now the question is,

1. How do I generate the name of the df column dynamically as `'SMA10' + 0915` and assign SMA value?
2. Assign the SMA value to each row of the stock in df to each columns in df

`x = datetime.now()`  #assuming time now to be 09:15

`xtime = x.strftime(%H%M)`

I tried using `globals()[df.loc[i, '''SMA10'+ xtime']] = 13.84`

Sample Data:

`df()`

| 'symbol' | 'SMA100915' | 'SMA100930' | 'SMA100945' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INFY | 1562.97 | 1564 | 1565.65 |
| RELIANCE | 2127 | 2129 | 2126.39 |

Comment: What is `i` in your tried code ?   Have you already got a loop looping on each row ?  It's unclear what you want to do with the 2nd part of questions:  `2. Assign the SMA ....`  please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a column to a `DataFrame` like you'd add a key/value to a dictionary, i.e. `df["your_key"] = some_vals`. You can construct your key however you want.

One wrinkle is that the values you assign should either be a single value or a sequence of values with the same number of elements as your `DataFrame` has rows. So in your case

```py
In [30]: from datetime import datetime

In [31]: import pandas

In [32]: df = pandas.DataFrame({"symbol": ["INFY", "RELIANCE"], "SMA1010915": [1562.97, 2127], "SMA100930": [15464, 2129],
    ...: "SMA100945": [1565.65, 2126.39]})

In [33]: time_str = datetime.now().strftime('%H%M')

In [34]: df["SMA10" + time_str] = [2000, 3000] # List of length two since there are two rows

In [35]: df
Out[35]:
     symbol  SMA1010915  SMA100930  SMA100945  SMA100938
0      INFY     1562.97      15464    1565.65       2000
1  RELIANCE     2127.00       2129    2126.39       3000

In [36]: new_time_str = "1230"

In [40]: df["SMA10" + new_time_str] = 100 # If single value, all rows get this

In [41]: df
Out[41]:
     symbol  SMA1010915  SMA100930  SMA100945  SMA100938  SMA101230
0      INFY     1562.97      15464    1565.65       2000        100
1  RELIANCE     2127.00       2129    2126.39       3000        100
```

If you want to assign values to individual rows, you can do that, too. I think it'd probably be easiest to index your `DataFrame` by the "symbol" column, so something like

```py
In [51]: by_symbol = df.set_index("symbol")
In [55]: by_symbol
Out[55]:
          SMA1010915  SMA100930  SMA100945
symbol
INFY         1562.97      15464    1565.65
RELIANCE     2127.00       2129    2126.39

In [56]: new_time_str = "1111"

In [57]: by_symbol.loc["INFY", "SMA10" + new_time_str] = 1234

In [58]: by_symbol
Out[58]:
          SMA1010915  SMA100930  SMA100945  SMA101111
symbol
INFY         1562.97      15464    1565.65     1234.0
RELIANCE     2127.00       2129    2126.39        NaN
```

Note that you could do this without indexing by symbol. In that case, you'd just do

```py
In [59]: df.loc[0, "SMA10" + new_time_str] = 1234

In [60]: df
Out[60]:
     symbol  SMA1010915  SMA100930  SMA100945  SMA101111
0      INFY     1562.97      15464    1565.65     1234.0
1  RELIANCE     2127.00       2129    2126.39        NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import time 

#Initialize data
data = {'SYMBOL':['INFY', 'RELIANCE'],
        'SMA100915':'',
        'SMA100930':'',
        'SMA100945':''}

#Create Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def fillSMA(df, xtime)
    #extract time as 0915
    xtime = xtime.strftime('%H%M')
    
    df_len = len(df)
    i=0
    
    while i < df_len:
        
        #Assign SMA to each row of DF (for each symbol/stock)
        df.loc[i, 'SMA10'+ xtime] = 1546
        
    #End of While Loop
#End of fillSMA


starttime= time(hour=9, minute=15, second=0)
endtime = time(hour=15, minute=15, second=0)

while time.time() <= endtime:
    fillSMA(df, time.time())
    time.sleep(900)
```